# Hyphenation exceptions specified by \hyphenation hyphenates some words differently

Tags: macros, errors, formatting, hyphenation

following the book *Mathematical Wrinting in English* by **Nicholas Higham** §8.22 in the third edition, I am trying to add hyphenation exceptions to my LaTeX template. However the `\hyphenation` macro doesn't seem to work in some cases. In below example the words are hyphenated as **dis-tributed** and **pen-alty**. Any ideas on how to force the specified hyphenation?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{testhyphens}

\hyphenation{dis-tribut-ed pen-al-ty}

\begin{document}

\begin{checkhyphens}
distributed penalty
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \showthe\righthyphenmin

Comment: The default value of `\righthyphenmin` for English-language documents is `3`. If you want to hyphenation immediately before the penultimate letter of the word, you need to set `\righthyphenmin=2`.